# How do I create a log file while scraping the web at the same time (Python 3)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am new to python and I am finding it really difficult to understand the whole concept of logging in Python. I am currently working on this web-scraping project using python 3. I have used BeautifulSoup4 to help me:
The code I've written below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import urllib3 
import urllib.request

web = "https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html"

page = urllib.request.urlopen(web) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page) 

print(soup.prettify())
```

Do you know how should I start? Where do I begin and what code am I supposed to write in order to create my log file? I am really confused, somebody please helpppppp me!!!!!!!
thank you!!

Comment: Why do you need a log file? The most basic thing to do is to open a new file and write to it whenever something important happens in the code. Just search for "Write to file python"

Comment: @CamJohnson26 Hi, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: What do you want to log? Just the url? The page that was downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

The cookbook gives you lots of great information. There are many choices, but the minimum is very easy. I've updated your code with a basic log implementation. Run your code then look at `my_logfile.txt` in your current working directory. You can fancify by implementing the examples in the cookbook.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import urllib3 
import urllib.request
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, filename='my_logfile.txt')
logger = logging.getLogger('scraper')

web = "https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html"

page = urllib.request.urlopen(web) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page) 

logger.info('loaded {}'.format(web))

print(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're dead-set on building a web scraper yourself okay, but take a look at https://scrapy.org/ which handles almost all the nasty bits of dealing with requests, retries, crawling sites in general, etc.

Logging in scrapy is handled by the built in `logging` module in python. https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html

If you do want to build it yourself, instead of using `print()` use the `logging` module directly. Docs at https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html and a handy collection of cookbook examples is at https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook